# Removing extra whitespace at end of RegExp?

Tags: javascript, regex, actionscript-3

I'm using this code to indent a block of text. It works fine but it adds white space to the end.

```
public var indentPattern:RegExp = /([\t ]*)(.*)$/gm;
public function indent(input:String, indentAmount:String = "\t"):String {
    if (input==null || input=="") return indentAmount;

    var indentedText:String = input.replace(indentPattern, indentAmount + "$1$2");
    return indentedText;
}
```

Test input data:

```
<style type="text/css">
    html, body {
        height:100%;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        line-height:.8;
    }

    *, *:before, *:after {
        -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
        box-sizing:border-box;
    }

</style>
```

Actual output:

```
    <style type="text/css">     
    html, body {        
        height:100%;        
        margin:0;       
        padding:0;      
        line-height:.8;     
    }       

    *, *:before, *:after {      
        -moz-box-sizing:border-box;     
        -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;      
        box-sizing:border-box;      
    }       



    </style>
```

Note: When I say white space at the end tabs are added at the end of the line after the semicolon. Try highlighting the text on the page to see what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that

```
([\t ]*)(.*)$
```

Can match an empty string. Therefore, an empty string is matched at the end of the line and `indentAmount` is placed there. Change it to:

```
([\t ]*)(.+)$
```

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/hN4jH5/2)

Or make the match start from the beginning of each line:

```
^([\t ]*)(.*)$
```

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/hN4jH5/3)

Answer (score 1):

If everything else is in place, try removing them before returning:

```
indentedText = indentedText.replace(/\s+$/g, '');
```

Comment: I think a more appropriate regex here would be `indentedText = indentedText.replace(/[ \t]+$/gm, '');`